# Find $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\left( 1 + \sqrt{2} + \sqrt[3]{3} + \dots \sqrt[n]{n} \right) \ln{2n+1 \over n}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I am looking for

$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\left( 1 + \sqrt{2} + \sqrt[3]{3} + \dots \sqrt[n]{n} \right) \ln{2n+1 \over n}$$
We notice $\ln{2n+1 \over n} = \ln\left({1 + {n+1 \over n}}\right)$. We also know that ${x \over 1 + x} \le \ln(1+x)$. From this, we get

$${n+1 \over 2n+1} \le \ln\left({1 + {n+1 \over n}}\right)$$

Then we notice $n \le 1 + \sqrt{2} + \sqrt[3]{3} + \dots \sqrt[n]{n}$, so
$$n{n+1 \over 2n+1} \le \left( 1 + \sqrt{2} + \sqrt[3]{3} + \dots \sqrt[n]{n} \right) \ln{2n+1 \over n}$$
$n{n+1 \over 2n+1} \to + \infty$, so
$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\left( 1 + \sqrt{2} + \sqrt[3]{3} + \dots \sqrt[n]{n} \right) \ln{2n+1 \over n} = + \infty$$
Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Yes. Even more straightforwardly: you don't need to evaluate the logarithm so "finely", just finding a very crude estimate, say $\ln\frac{2n+1}{n}>\ln 2 >0$, is enough.

Comment: Yes. The reasoning is correct. You could have also inferred that $\sum\limits_{x=0}^{\infty} x^{\frac{1}{x}} = \infty$ by checking that the $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} x^{\frac{1}{x}} = \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} e^{\frac{\ln x}{x}} = 1 \neq 0$ implying that the sum diverges.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is correct. But you could say that all terms in bracket (the first part) are greater than 1, and second part goes to $ln(2)$, which is non zero. So the total limit goes to Infinity.